# Scroll position jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have this page with a full-width video header.
After the user scrolls the header size I remove the header like this:

```
var startScroll = $('.header').outerHeight();
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

  /*if (scrollTop > startScroll) {
    $('.inline-menu').addClass('menu-fixed').css('top', adminBar);
  } else {
    $('.inline-menu').removeClass('menu-fixed').removeAttr('style');
  }*/

  if(scrollTop > startScroll) {
    // do something
    $('.header').addClass('header-remove');
    $('.wrap').addClass('wrap-remove');
    $('.inline-menu').addClass('menu-fixed').css('top', adminBar);

    /*$(".inline-menu").css({top, startScroll;
    startScroll = 0;

    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    $('.main').scrollTo(0,0);*/
  }
});
```

The issue is that the page jumps the first content "news" once you are scrolling pulling the page directly to "Management Positionierung". Can't figure it out why.

The site is: http://kk.lopezi.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is because you scroll down actual scroll bar down and remove the title page which makes you end up at Management Positionierung not news since your **scroll bar is pulled down already** and **new is at the very top**. It will be solved either you do not scroll down but just pull up(using transition or animframe) and then remove or do not remove title page at all.

[image: 123]

this is your first page where scroll bar is at very top and when you click arrow,

[image]

it scrolls down and does transition at the same time . so you **end up at the middle** of docment, not the top.

[image]

and because header is removed news section is not at the middle anymore, it's at the very top where header was. since you scrolled down already, your **scroll stays at the middle** while news is now at the very top. this is why I suggest you either only do transition or do not remove header.

[image]

so this is how it would work if you choose to not remove header, so that news stays middle not top.

if you want to remove header, you could use this code after removing header.

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

which will scroll to x:0, y:0.

Comment: Sorry but I did not catch your answer

Comment: It works properly after you scroll down one or two menu items and start from top, the issue is on the transition, when the header is removed

Comment: thank you for taking the time and explaining the issue. However it does not solve my problem since it is a requirement to remove the header after the user scrolls down. There should be a way to push the page to Top after the header is removed, no?

Comment: you might want to use window.scrollTo(), but i am concerned about smoothness

Answer (score 0):

So this is the piece of added/edit code that solved the issue

```
if(scrollTop > startScroll) {
// do something
$('.header').addClass('header-remove');
$('.wrap').addClass('wrap-remove');
$('.inline-menu').addClass('menu-fixed').css('top', adminBar);


window.scrollTo(0,0);
startScroll = 22222; //make the condition always true so it executes only once
```

}